# Make Google chart show past X number of data samples and not just past 3 days

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am using angular-google-chart and angularjs to display charts.
https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart

I have a set of data consisting of 100 data points in json which looks like this;

```
[{
    value: 400,
    time: "2014-05-07 13:51:39"
},
{
    value: 425.28,
    time: "2014-05-04 16:19:58"
},
{
    value: 425.6,
    time: "2014-05-03 16:19:56"
},
// rest of samples fall before 2014-05-04 time range
]
```

The problem is that on the Google Chart, it only shows the first 2 samples because for some reason, the chart only shows samples of past recent 3 days.

Here is the relevant javascript code for configuring Google Chart options.

```
var google_chart_options =
{
    'hAxis': {
        'title': "Date",
        'format': "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    },
};

var horizontal_axis = {id: "t", label: "Date", type: "datetime"};
var vertical_axis= {id: "s", label: "value", type: "number"};
var type = 'LineChart';
```

I have some questions;

1. What options should I use to get Google Chart to display data points of past X days or X number of data points?
2. What options should I use to get Google Chart to display data points from, say, `2014-05-01 16:30` to `2014-05-07 13:30`?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your 2nd question.

> What options should I use to get Google Chart to display data points
>   from, say, 2014-05-01 16:30 to 2014-05-07 13:30?

Here is the code.

```
var google_chart_options =
{
    'hAxis': {
        'title': "Date",
        'format': "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
         viewWindow: {
                      min: new Date(2014, 4, 1, 16, 30), //note that month lies from 0 to 11 (December)
                      max: new Date(2014, 4, 7, 13, 30),                      
         },
    }
};
```

The key lies in the viewWindow options under hAxis.